# Closed form roots of sum of exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function, roots

Do anyone know a way to solve an equation like the following (over the complex numbers)?
$1+2^z+3^z=0$
I certainly cannot. I've tried by hand, and by mathematica, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no closed form solution for this kind of equation. The particular one in your question has no solutions since the left hand side is always greater than 1.

Comment: Well, complex numbers should also be considered

Comment: Then you should really say this in the question. And write $z$ for a complex number.